# Not sending POST parameters

Tags: java, android, http-post

I've tried several things but my android app is not sending post parameters. I run the app on a virtual device. This is the code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(page);   

        HttpParams httpParams = client.getParams();
        httpParams.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 20000);

        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("username", "abcd");
        obj.put("password", "1234");
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It should send a post request to a PHP page. This page displays the output of the POST array:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

When I run the app, it displays an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There was a htaccess file that redirected all non www pages.

Answer (score 1):

thats because you're sending JSON

standard php $_POST is build from key-value pairs
so you should post key1=value1&key2=value2

or you should read from

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
```

or

```
<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```

and use

```
json_decode( $postdata );
```

PHP will not automatically decode json for you

you can also use another approach and POST your json like data=YourJsonCode

and then decode it using json_decode( $_POST['data'] );

Comment: When I do: `var_dump(json_decode($postdata));` it returns NULL

Comment: Nope is displays nothing :( But i've also tried other ways to send a request with post parameters without json and also won't work.

Comment: like post.setEntity(new StringEntity("key1=value1", "UTF-8")); ?

Comment: in that case you should probably change content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Tried the other way you said and changed the content type but the $_POST is an empty array and the $postdata (php://input) is empty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17603/discussion-between-mysqlerror-and-jochem-gruter)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending url encoded name/value pairs.  You can also use `EntityUtils` to convert the response to a `String` for you.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(page);

HttpParams httpParams = client.getParams();
httpParams.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 20000);

post.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

List<NameValuePair> formParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "abcd"));
formParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1234"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formParams,HTTP.UTF_8);
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
```

Comment: THanks for your answer. But it isn't working. The `$_POST` array is empty and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` returns GET